# Androidx project can't recognize the class of library using android.support.v7

Tags: android

I'm using a class of library that inherited from `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`. Now my project is migrated to androidx. By using this class called `MessagesList` and trying to find it by id,  I'll get a syntax error:

```
Inferred type <MessagesList> is not a subtype of view
```

A code with an synthax error:

```
messagesList = requireView().findViewById(R.id.messagesList_messageList_messages)
```

I have set `android.enableJetifier=true` and `android.useAndroidX=true` in the gradle.properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Just adding the androidx recycler view dependency separately is needed.

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```